# What UX principle would describe interoperability with the customer journey?

Tags: ux-field

The customer journey extends beyond a tool, and mapping the journey can help identify interoperability gaps or requirements with external systems (computer or human):

- The user needs discovery and navigation through a search engine (SEO)
- The users need easy capture in tools like Evernote.
- Sharing information or links with other people.
- The users need screen-reading and the article mode in Safari.
- The users need export to CSV for further processing.
- The user needs to copy and paste the table into a different system.

Is there a non-verbose headline to encompass this concept as a single principle or statement that it´s a owner priority to make functional solutions which work beyond cliking on nice buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Um, "Required functionality" ? Or "Content needs to be findable and shareable"

Comment: Yeah, maybe a split of sorts would work. Findable and sharable would include SEO and optimization of sharing. And then activities like copy info from somewhere place into the application, or automatic information gathering would be a requirement. Specification at that level might be a bit too specific for some of our service designers, but clarity in expectations isn´t always a bad thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking along the lines of overall customer experience, by any chance?

Here's a link with more information: https://blog.hubspot.com/service/what-is-customer-experience

Comment: I´m pretty sure UX is right "to meet the exact needs of the customer, without fuss or bother" ...  https://www.nngroup.com/articles/definition-user-experience/   (i.e. if you need to link to a place, and the app is designed in a way where you need to write 10 stepts to get there, rather than just sharing a link .. it qualifies as "fuss and bother". :-)